# How to sort and pair as per Keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

First of all i am new to Nosql database but for my app tried using firebase for the first time.
I am creating an App about something and in that app i have applicants which submit some amount of money every month at specific date
in order to store that in my firebase Firestore i created a collection name transaction and in that for a user i am saving all his transactions.

```
transaction2018(collection) -> userId1(collection) -> { ....result1 }
                        -> userId2(collection) -> { ....result2 }
                     -> userId3(collection) -> { ....result3 }

transaction2019(collection) -> userId1(collection) -> { ....result1 }
                         -> userId2(collection) -> { ....result2 }
                         -> userId3(collection) -> { ....result3 }
```

> That is the reason i have designed like that so for every user i can
>   get all his transaction in one object One more thing in my resuly
>   object amount_2,data_2 two is actually month(feb) and if i dont do
>   this that I'll have to go deeper something like :

```
transaction2018 -> userId1 -> January -> {amount,date.....}
                        -> February
                        .....
```

> which is not actually a good practice in Nosql databases.

I am using NoSql database and the result which I am getting is in below format,
How can I convert this in my desired format after fetching data:

```
let result = {
  amount_2       : "1000",
  amount_3       : "1200",
  date_2         : "15/2/2019",
  date_3         : "15/3/2019",
  modeOfPayment_2: "Cash",
  modeOfPayment_3: "Cash",
  note_2         : "áßðáßðáßð↵áß",
  note_3         : "",
  refNum_2       : "11111",
  refNum_3       : "Fffff",
  submittedByID_2: "T62tgJcjieSJsAEJT69VfpRc5Mw2",
  submittedByID_3: "T62tgJcjieSJ"
};
```

I want something like:

```
var output = [
  {
    amount2,
    date2,
    ....
  },
  {
   amount3,
   date3,
   ...... 
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you read about how to format your code here on SO?

Comment: First of all, you should design the database better – that's not how a database is supposed to be used.

Comment: does it look good now ?

Comment: @JJJ i am using NoSql database ,already mentioned before

Comment: @Eddysapata consider updating your question to show us what you have attempted so far

Comment: My bad, but that's the wrong format even for a NoSQL database. Each item should be in their own (sub)document, not crammed into one.

Comment: @Eddysapata If you read [ask] you will find that a user posting a question should make a proper research and show an effort of their own, and your clearly haven't done that.

Comment: @JJJ I have edited the question how you will get the answer. :)

Comment: @DacreDenny I can do with iterating over it and can get data as per my need but i was in search of most eloquent way.
P.S-> And that is the reason i have not tried at first place.!

Comment: This should not be solved in JavaScript but in your database structure and query.

Comment: *"i have designed like that so for every user i can get all his transaction in one object"* – but now you want to split it to different objects anyway, after getting that one object? That doesn't make any sense. Make the database structure match the desired result.

Comment: *"which is not actually a good practice in Nosql databases"* – yes it is. Store the dates as actual dates instead of strings and query the database with a date range. You'll get the desired end result directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in plain JavaScript using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build an intermediate dictionary whose keys are the digits at the end of your keys. This will group your key/value pairs by this digit, you can then get your result by taking the values of this dictionary using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

With `key.match(/(\d+)$/)` you can extract the number at the end of your keys and use it as the key for the intermediate dictionary.

Using a positive lookahead regex `/_(?=\d)/`, you can remove the underscore if it precedes a digit a the end of your keys to get your new key names.

```js
const data = {
  amount_2       : "1000",
  amount_3       : "1200",
  date_2         : "15/2/2019",
  date_3         : "15/3/2019",
  modeOfPayment_2: "Cash",
  modeOfPayment_3: "Cash",
  note_2         : "áßðáßðáßð↵áß",
  note_3         : "",
  refNum_2       : "11111",
  refNum_3       : "Fffff",
  submittedByID_2: "T62tgJcjieSJsAEJT69VfpRc5Mw2",
  submittedByID_3: "T62tgJcjieSJ"
};

const result = Object.values(Object.entries(data).reduce((dict, [key, val]) => {
  // reduce is called for each key/value pair in your input data
  // here we add the key/value pair in the proper entry based
  // on the number extracted at the end
  const num = key.match(/(\d+)$/); // get number at end of key
  const newKey = key.replace(/_(?=\d)/, ''); // remove underscore before digit
  dict[num] = dict[num] || {}; // create a default entry if needed
  dict[num][newKey] = val; // set value for the new key
  return dict; // return intermediate dictionary
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the use of a single regular expression to extract both the name and number from each key of the input (`results`) object via the following:

```
const [, name, number] =  key.match(/^(.*)_(\d+)$/);
```

Where `key` is the current key of `result` being iterated. This single regular expression will return the `name` and `number` of the `key` according to the format you have prescribed. A full solution can be achieve independent of lodash, as shown:

```js
let result = {
  amount_2       : "1000",
  amount_3       : "1200",
  date_2         : "15/2/2019",
  date_3         : "15/3/2019",
  modeOfPayment_2: "Cash",
  modeOfPayment_3: "Cash",
  note_2         : "áßðáßðáßð↵áß",
  note_3         : "",
  refNum_2       : "11111",
  refNum_3       : "Fffff",
  submittedByID_2: "T62tgJcjieSJsAEJT69VfpRc5Mw2",
  submittedByID_3: "T62tgJcjieSJ"
};

/* Compose Object.values() and Object.entries() with reduce. Here we get
the key/value pairs (entries) of the input "results" object, and reduce
the key/values into an object of nsted objects of key/values grouped by 
number.
We then aquire an array of the grouped objects using Object.values() */
const groupedResult = Object.values(Object.entries(result).reduce((output, [key,value]) => {
   
  /* Extract key and number parts of current entry of result object */
  const [, name, number] =  key.match(/^(.*)_(\d+)$/);
  
  /* Fetch or insert (empty) object for the number corresponding to
  this entries key */
  const group = output[ number ] = output[ number ] || {}
  
  /* Compose a key with number suffix and insert value into group
  object for composed key */
  group[ `${name}${ number }` ] = value;
  
  /* Return current output object for next iteration of reduce */
  return output;

}, {}))

console.log(groupedResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function using `_.flow()` that breaks the object to an array of entries (`_.pairs()`), groups by the number in the key, and then maps the result back to an object (`_.fromPairs`), and updates the keys (`_.mapKeys()`).

```js
const { flow, toPairs, groupBy, partialRight: pr, map, fromPairs, mapKeys } = _;

const pattern = /_+(\d+)$/;
const getKeyId = ([k]) => (k.match(pattern) || [''])[0];

const fn = flow(
  toPairs, // convert to entries
  pr(groupBy, getKeyId), // group by the number in the key
  pr(map, flow( // map back to object
    fromPairs, // combine the entries in the group
    pr(mapKeys, (v, k) => k.replace(pattern, '$1')) // update the keys
  ))
);

const data = {
  amount_2       : "1000",
  amount_3       : "1200",
  date_2         : "15/2/2019",
  date_3         : "15/3/2019",
  modeOfPayment_2: "Cash",
  modeOfPayment_3: "Cash",
  note_2         : "áßðáßðáßð↵áß",
  note_3         : "",
  refNum_2       : "11111",
  refNum_3       : "Fffff",
  submittedByID_2: "T62tgJcjieSJsAEJT69VfpRc5Mw2",
  submittedByID_3: "T62tgJcjieSJ"
};

const result = fn(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the same solution using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const { flow, toPairs, groupBy, map, fromPairs, mapKeys, replace } = _;

const pattern = /_+(\d+)$/;
const getKeyId = ([k]) => (k.match(pattern) || [''])[0];

const fn = flow(
  toPairs, // convert to entries
  groupBy(getKeyId), // group by the number in the key
  map(flow( // map back to object
    fromPairs, // combine the entries in the group
    mapKeys(replace(pattern, '$1')) // update the keys
  ))
);

const data = {
  amount_2       : "1000",
  amount_3       : "1200",
  date_2         : "15/2/2019",
  date_3         : "15/3/2019",
  modeOfPayment_2: "Cash",
  modeOfPayment_3: "Cash",
  note_2         : "áßðáßðáßð↵áß",
  note_3         : "",
  refNum_2       : "11111",
  refNum_3       : "Fffff",
  submittedByID_2: "T62tgJcjieSJsAEJT69VfpRc5Mw2",
  submittedByID_3: "T62tgJcjieSJ"
};

const result = fn(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By now it seems you want to group fields into objects depending on numbers in tail of each index.

```
const result = [];
_.each(inputObject, (key, value) => {
    const [,keyName, indexPart] = key.match(/^(.*)_(\d+)$/);
    result[indexPart] = result[indexPart] || {};
    result[indexPart][keyName] = value;
});
```